# How to speed up first unique character lookup

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm solving [387. First Unique Character in a String](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/description/) LeetCode problem defined as:

> Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> s = "leetcode"
> return 0.
>
> s = "loveleetcode",
> return 2.
> ```
>
> **Note:** You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.

Taking advantage of the input being fully lowercase ASCII I created two bit vectors to track when we encounter a character for the first and second time.

Can below code be improved further? LeetCode says that below code is better than 94.33% solutions. What else could have been done by the last 5.67% solutions that they were better?

```
class Solution {

  public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    int firstSpot = 0;
    int secondSpot = 0;
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
      int mask = 1 << c - 'a';
      if ((firstSpot & mask) == 0) {
        firstSpot |= mask;
      } else if ((secondSpot & mask) == 0) {
        secondSpot |= mask;
      }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (char c : chars) {
      int mask = 1 << c - 'a';
      if ((secondSpot & mask) == 0) {
         return i;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return -1;
  }

}
```

[image: LeetCode score]

Are there tricks that can be done to improve the LeetCode score? It seems that enhanced `for-each` loop performs better than standard `for` loop but I can't prove it, It's an observation based on few of my previous submissions.

Comment: This question is better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your post could get a better reception at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Re: "LeetCode says that below code is better than 94.33% solutions": My impression is that LeetCode is doing an unscientific microbenchmark that might depend on random factors (such as the other load on their servers at submission-time). So I'm not sure this figure is meant to be taken very seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got **98.58**% with this:-

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    int count[] = new int[122 - 96];
    final char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        count[chars[i] - 97]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (count[chars[i] - 97] == 1)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can get it to 100% by adding `int setup=([] {cin.tie(0);ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);return 0;})();` to the beginning of the code.

Comment: @0x499602D2 java equivalent please

Comment: Right this is Java not C++. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ruakh says in a comment, the precise timings produced by leetcode are subject to a certain amount of randomness, so they should be taken with a grain of salt:

> My impression is that LeetCode is doing an unscientific microbenchmark that might depend on random factors.

Still, it is possible to speed your first loop up quite a bit by getting rid of the tests. The following loop is functionally equivalent; although it sets the variables more often, changing the value of a local integer variable costs less than testing whether it is necessary to change:

```
for (char c : chars) {
  int mask = 1 << c - 'a';
  secondSpot |= mask & firstSpot;
  firstSpot |= mask;
}
```

(It's important that the assignment be in that order, so that the first one does nothing if the character hasn't yet been seen.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    //  0x60 < 'a' < 'z' < 0x80
    private final byte[] bCounter = new byte[0x80];
    private final int[] iCounter = new int[0x80];

    public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        if ((len & 0xff) == len) {
            Arrays.fill(bCounter, 0x60, 0x80, (byte)-1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                bCounter[s.charAt(i)]++;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (bCounter[s.charAt(i)] == 0)
                    return i;
        } else {
            Arrays.fill(iCounter, 0x60, 0x80, -1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                iCounter[s.charAt(i)]++;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (iCounter[s.charAt(i)] == 0)
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```