# How to find the index of the first unique character of the given string in Java?

Tags: java

Can someone please explain me the following program from Line 11 to Line 17.

```
import java.util.*;
public  class  Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "wresource";
        System.out.println("Original String: "+s);
        System.out.println("Index of the First unique character of the given string is at : "+first_Uniq_Char(s));
    }

    public static int first_Uniq_Char(String s) {
         int[] freq = new int[256];
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {   //Line 11
            freq[c - 'a']++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (freq[s.charAt(i) - 'a'] == 1) return i;
        }
        return -1;  //Line17
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
Original String: wresource
Index of the First unique character of the given string is at : 0
```

.

Comment: No, too broad. What more exactly is it you don't understand? Note that stackoverflow is a site for specific programming (related) questions and not a tutorial site.

Comment: am new to java and have no one to help me understand the logic.Am not able to understand the two 'For' loops and the return -1. I mean, what is the logic applied here to check the first index of unique character in the string.

Comment: The first loop uses an array to count the frequency of the characters by using an array that represent each ASCII character. By subtracting 'a' from the character then the first index of the array represents 'a' , the second 'b' and so on. (Note that java char is an int between 0-255). The second loop simply check for characters with count being 1

Comment: Ok,thanks for the explanation.

Comment: can you please exlain what is 'return -1' means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up first unique character lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383866/how-to-speed-up-first-unique-character-lookup)

Comment: thanks for the link.But it looks advanced for me..I just want to know what does 'return -1' means here.

Comment: It’s a way to say no answer was found since if an answer is found the result will always be 0 or positive since what is returned is an index of the position in the string of that unique character. It is a common solution to denote that nothing was found that you will see elsewhere in java

Answer (score 4):

freq[] is an array which holds each element frequency i.e.

freq[w] =1

freq[r] =2

freq[e] =2

freq[s] =1  , etc

freq[c - 'a']++; this line converts your each character to ASCII code

Comment: Thanks for you inputs. Why ' freq[c-'a']++ ' is used.Can you help me understand this

Answer (score 1):

As we know array index is of type integer only, we cannot have a[c] ( c is a character).

So what we have done is we have converted c into ASCII  i.e.  freq[c-'a'] means 99 - 97  = 3 ( a in ASCII is 97 and C is 99) 
freq[3] = 3 is same as freq[c]

Comment: what is return -1 means?

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers, update your first one instead